# DIY Quadrature Encoder?

Tags: arduino, encoder, diy

Really struggling with making encoders work in my leonardo board, i could probably go the 20 ppr encoder way but i need it to be optical and not electrical/mechanical.

I was thinking about using 2 IR counters together , so about 2x IR Transmitters and 2x IR Receivers, each counter with its own Signal output and voltage wires being common.

[Example of IR Counter](https://electropeak.com/learn/interfacing-lm393-infrared-speed-sensor-with-arduino/)

[Example of my idea being done (?)](https://frobotme.wordpress.com/2014/05/25/a-simple-diy-quadrature-encoder-for-arduino-using-optical-sensors/)

Would like to get some opinions in this project.

Comment: Old-fashioned computer mice have optical encoders that you might be able to salvage. If you want to change the count per revolution, you might be able to construct a new wheel, either by 3D printing or otherwise.

Comment: about how old lol, i dont think i have any if they need to be too old.

Comment: The mechanical ones with balls inside

Comment: some new mice  have optical encoders on the scroll wheel

Comment: @tote46 If your mouse has a ball on the bottom, like [this](https://imgur.com/RLxNWN9), it's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

> 20 ppr encoder way but i need it to be optical and not electrical/mechanical.

Optical encoders are available commercially, they're typically just a bit more expensive than the electromechanical alternative, and not usually needed for 20 pulses per rotation – that's a rather low resolution. The cost might be worth not reinventing the wheel. Quite literally that is, you're reinventing the encoder wheel.

> I was thinking about using 2 IR counters together , so about 2x IR Transmitters and 2x IR Receivers, each counter with its own Signal output and voltage wires being common.

You mean like these common components?

[image]
<sup>Digikey website: Omron EE-SX4070</sup>

They are called optical interrupters.

There's a [full category](https://www.digikey.de/short/zzj3cbn7) of these on your favourite electronics distributor, and they come in "output that is low drive strength for a microcontroller input" and "high current sink for direct action" (e.g., safety interlocks that just turn off a laser when a lid is opened).

For getting the 20 pulses in an encoder way: Assume a slotted disk with equally wide slots and inter-slot-space; 20 of these slots.

[image: Picture of a part of a disk]
<sup>Sketch of what such a disk would look like; from the datasheet of the component shown and linked to above</sup>

Either 3D-print a fixture so that the second sensor is offset at an angle of 4N+1 of a quarter slot period from the first, or have two slotted disk with their own interrupter offset by by a quarter of a slot period angle on the same rod.